# weird BT issue Pixel 5

Tags: bluetooth

BT Shure TW2 in ears connect fine to Mac.  But intermittent to Pixel 5, whether Wifi or cell/data.

BT speaker is no issue with either.
I've reset BT/WiFi.  Re-paired. Re-started the Pixel 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: So BT pairing fails with Pixel 5?

Comment: With in ears only.  BT speaker is fine.

Comment: aOS 14 11.5.23
BT connects to P5, and while it says OK, the sound is awful, like sideband, no fideity.  Eventually, after enough tries, it's OK.

Comment: May be it connects as Handy-free headset? AFIAR codecs got Handy-free are just for voice (low bandwidth codec).

Comment: no.  previously worked fine.

Comment: Previous to what ?  Please update your question with answers in teh comment and more detail about what is happening.

Comment: previous to the Nov update.
The BT in-ears have no issue connecting to a Mac desktop.
The P5 has no issue connecting to a BT speaker.
But intermittently, although they connect to the P5 every time, they have the sound of sideband, like garbled 8bit.

Sometimes restarting the P5 fixes it, sometimes resetting WiFi/BT fixes it.
Sometimes, time fixes it.  
Sometimes re-pairing on the phone or from the case, as Shure suggests, fixes it.
I can find or make no consistency in the problem.

I want to think it's the Shures themselves, but they connect and work fine with the Mac every time.

Comment: appears to be slow changeover to dala/cell.